# AngularJS $ not working without including jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have some jquery code using $ in my controller. When I include jquery in the page, then it works fine but when I remove jQuery then I get following error:

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I read online that jquery has inbuilt small footprint jquery named jQlite then why I get the error:

```
$('.scrollProductPicker , .scrollTailoredSupport').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Angular uses jQLite. jQLite is enough for angular to work. if you are using any jquery code you should include it

Comment: Please do check if you have some JQuery functionality in your page.

Comment: If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite.". [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely good. but I want that smooth scroll feature. Couldn't use angular-smoothscroll directive as the link is outside of my angular app and the target anchor is inside the angular app. I ended up with using vanilla javascipt for smooth scroll

Answer (score 2):

in Angular JS `angular.element` is used as an alias for `$` or "JQuery", which is part of jqlite and hence if you are using `$` directly you need to add the reference of jQuery. more details you can find at this link [Angular JS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Answer (score 1):

Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite.

jLite is avaiable here [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

So you cannot do this:

```
angular.element("body"); //DOES NOT WORK!
```

However, you can do:

```
angular.element(document.body); //DOES WORK!
```

jLite has just a sub set of functions from jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

@Ramesh & @ThiagoPXP has given the correct answers. But you can still make full use of Angular to select any elements like so:

```
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("div.foo"));
// or
angular.element(document.querySelector("#my-page ul.bar"));
```

You can make your code simpler by registering them as methods in Angular:

```
angular.findAll = function(selector) {
    return angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
}
```

And then you can write easily as:

```
angular.findAll("div.foo");
// or
angular.findAll("#my-page ul.bar");
```

Or simpler (to use syntax like jQuery):

```
window.$ = function(selector) {
    return angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
}

$("#my-page ul.bar") // will work
```

But, if you do not include jQuery, Angular will use a small version of jQuery i.e. jqlite which will not have every method available as jQuery.